# Rails 3 app doesn't redirect after AJAX form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I have an Authlogic login form with `:remote => true` that does a little inline validation with an RJS template if the user/password isn't valid. This works fine, but when the credentials *are* valid, it doesn't properly redirect elsewhere.

Here's the controller that responds to the form input:

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  before_filter :require_no_user, :only => [:new, :create]
  before_filter :require_user, :only => :destroy

  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_session.save     
        flash[:notice] = "Login successful!"
        format.html { redirect_to account_url }
      else
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_user_session.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Logout successful!"
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

The `format.js` part works but if the user/password are good (`format.html`), nothing happens. However, if I look a development.log, it *is* requesting the account_url page. It's just not redirecting you in the browser. I think it's returning the account page via AJAX and I really just want a normal redirect.

The HTML for the form is this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(
:user_session, @user_session, 
:url => { :controller => 'user_sessions', :action => "create" },
:html => { :id => 'login-dropdown' }, :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a way to fix it. Per http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/168406#945053, I added the following to my application controller:

```
def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
  if request.xhr?
    render(:update) {|page| page.redirect_to(options)}
  else
    super(options, response_status)
  end
end
```

This prevents the redirect response from being delivered via xhr. If there's a more "correct" way of doing this in the controller, I'd like to hear it, though.

Comment: This looks like more elegant way than `render :js => "window.location = ...` in contoller, but it gives me `ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template controller/update, application/update with {:handlers=>...`

Comment: Oh, that's cuz I'm using jQuery. And `jrails` kinda outdated, pity

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below :

in allpication.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).ajaxError( function(e, xhr, options){
    if("401" == xhr.responseText)
    {
       $(location).attr('href','/users/sign_in');
    }
  });
})
```

and controller's method has below code:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to @new_user_session_url}
    format.js { render :text=>'401' ,:status=>401}
end
```

But I think there is better way to do so....

Answer (score 0):

```
app
 views
   user_sessions
     create.js.erb(create file this)
```

in your create action add this code

```
 def create
  @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])

respond_to do |format|
  if @user_session.save     
    flash[:notice] = "Login successful!"
    @url = account_url
  end
 format.js
end
```

end

in your "create.js.erb"

```
window.location.replace(<%= @url %>);
```